# Replaying Client Hello from previous session

Tags: networking, ssl, wireshark, tcpreplay

I am basically testing an SSL server. I need to capture the client hello and then replay the same client hello with exact same field values. Here are the steps that I performed-
1) Captured the client hello with wireshark
2)Exported the specified packet (TCP 3 way handshake and Client hello)
3)Replayed it with tcpreplay.

The packet gets replayed but I am not getting any response from the server. Is it the normal behavior for a good SSL server?

Thanks